# How to add values from one to another data class?

Tags: kotlin

is it actually possible to connect two data classes by ID and then copy a value if IDs are equal??

```
data class Discount( val ID:String,val discountPrice:String)
data class Catalog( val ID:String,val price:String, name:String, desc:String, discountPrice:String?)

var catalog: Catalog? = eshopArticles?.let { Json.decodeFromString(it) }
var discounts: Discount? = priceListItems?.let { Json.decodeFromString(it) }
```

**Catalog** has over 4000 items and I need to copy discountPrice from **Discount** class to that Catalog..

Comment: `Catalog` is a normal object, it can't have x amount of items. It is not a collection. Do you have a collection (list,array,set,etc) that contains multiple `Catalog` and another one that contains multiple `Discount`? If so, what types are they? Is there an assurance that a single `Discount` object exists for each `Catalog` item? What should happen if 2 `Discount` objects contain the same id?

Comment: Also, just noticed, `name`, `desc`, `discountPrice` are not fields of the `Catalog` class, just parameters of its constructor. What is the actual field name of `discountPrice`? Also is it a `var`? Does it have a custom setter?

Comment: edited.... IDs are unique and never repeated in list...sorry if its not clear. This is my first app that Im creating...